# codeigniter required to store flashdata in for-each loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, foreach, controller

[image: Image show the content on which operations are performed]

As shown in image it is content of may page table
here whatever is in curly braces that is dynamic content...
it should be load dynamically...

if it is page then it should go for that page content and it may happen that page contains dynamic content too...

Now, for recursive call of that **i want to store that data in `flash data` temporary** but that is in `foreach loop` and may be more than one page need to load in `flash data` with name page......
what should i do...??

is there is another way to do this...??
please help me thank you...

```
public function page($page = 'home') {
    $text = $data['page']['content'];
    $regex = '/{\K[^}]*(?=})/m';
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
    exit;
    if ($matches) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
            $menu[] = $value;
            $v1 = explode(':', $value);
            if ($v1[0] == 'page') {
                $data['page'] = $this->page($v1[1]);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('page', $data['page']);
            } else if ($v1[0] == 'menu_list') {
                $data["menu"] = $this->pages_model->get_menu($v1[1]);
        } else if ($v1[0] == 'partial')
                $data["partial"] = $this->pages_model->get_partial($v1[1]);
            else {

            }
            if (isset($data['page'])) {
            } else if (isset($data['menu'])) {

            } else if (isset($data['partial'])) {

            }
        }
    } else {

    }
    //print_r($data);
    return $this->load->view('pages', $data);
}
```

Comment: The session flash data only shows up after page redirect.

Comment: that's right but i want to store array in flashdata it is possible...??